# User specific search in Solr

Tags: .net, search, solr

I have a few documents in solr where the user can search data. Now I want to hide some documents from the user except you have specific access to it. There are two kind of accesses:

- The document is hidden for every user except for user with Id 1,2,3
- The document is hidden for every user except for user from group "premium"

In the Administration you can manage who has access to which document, so the Id or groups can change on the fly.

What's a good practice to implement this issue? I can probably work with atomic updates, but it doesn't seem to be fast or a good practice.

Here is an example of the document:

```
 {
        "Id":"10000093",
        "Active":true,
        "Title":"Title",
        "ShortDescription":"ShortDescription",
        "Order":5,
        "Categories":["Category 1", "Category 2"],
        "Keywords":["Keyword 1", "Keyword 2"]
        "_version_":1620359096543739904
 },
```

Comment: What does your document looks like ?

Comment: Have you actually tried updating the document with that information? That information will have to be stored somewhere, and I can't see why updating a "available_for"-field would be so expensive compared to alternative solutions

Comment: I added an example of the document. Haven't mention it because it's nothing complex. Just a simple json without a hierarchy. I could create a list with the userId's who have access, but wouldn't a list with a few thousend entry slow down the search for the document extremly? What if someone uploads a new version of the document, the list would be lost.